# Как убрать не нужные пробелы в строке

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Дана строка:

```
String str = "770 601 001";
```

если прописывать так:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

и так

```
replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

и так

```
replaceAll("","")
```

и так

```
replaceAll(""," ")
```

результат будет таким

```
770 601 001
```

а нужно :

```
770601001
```

Проблема в том, что значение переменной я не прописываю руками, а получаю скажем из файла и после его считывания мне нужно привести в порядок эту переменную, чтоб можно было ее дальше использовать. И когда я пытаюсь убрать пробелы всеми выше указанными способами, пробелы остаются, но если взять к примеру самому прописать значения через пробел то все работает. Как такое может быть?

Comment: str.replaceAll(" ","");

Comment: можно и так попробовать `replaceAll("\\s+","")` + используется когда больше чем один пробел, так же можно воспользоваться комментом выше :)

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: `"770 601 001".replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", "")`

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно такая запись в replaceAll  помогла решить проблему!

Answer (score 1):

Это должно помочь

```
st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

Comment: Пробовал, результат такой же

Comment: Попробуйте так еще st.replaceAll(" ","");

Comment: Пробовал, не получается все равно нужно результата...

Comment: Именно так пробовали? Потому что то что у вас в вопросе, там немного другой вариант

Comment: да именно так, тут по всей видимости в чем то другом проблема

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
String withoutWhitespace = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(whitespaces);
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.String,%20char%29). Либо создать функцию:

```
public static String removeSpace(String s) {
    String withoutspaces = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != ' ')
            withoutspaces += s.charAt(i);

    }
    return withoutspaces;

}
```

### UPDATE

Вы используете три слеша:

```
str.replaceAll("\\\s","")
```

вместо двух:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

Вот [тут](https://www.onlinegdb.com/S16oP9qcU) попробовал с двумя слешами и все работает так как вам и нужно. Так же это касается `str.replaceAll("\\s+","")`.

Comment: Не работает так тоже

Comment: Да увидел,спасибо, но у меня все равно результат такой же, может дело в чем то другом

Comment: покажите код который вы используете для считывания данных и для обработки пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "770 601 001";

String newStr = str.replace(" ","");

System.out.println(newStr);
```